# What is a C++ Profile?

Tags: c++

In the CppCon 2023 keynotes, Bjarne Stroustrup mentioned the idea of a *profile*, but didn't explain exactly how it would be implemented. In the context, I understood this is not related to profiling a program.

What is a profile in C++ context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its CppCon 2023 talk, Bjarne Stroustrup mentioned what he coined *Safety Profiles* in [P2816](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2816r0.pdf):

> A safety profile is a set of guarantees enforced by an implementation. A profile presents the
> programmer with a set of rules and library components that together delivers the desired guarantees.

In this paper, Stroustrup explains that major actors are turning their back to C++ in favour of memory-managed programming languages (e.g. C#, Java, ...). He then proposed to introduce some standardisation to aleviate C++'s capability to express code *"with no violations of the type system, no resource leaks, no memory corruption, no garbage collector, no limitation of expressiveness or performance degradation compared to well-written modern C++"*.

Comment: https://github.com/BjarneStroustrup/profiles